# Is SvelteKit not able to reverse an array in time for runtime?

Tags: arrays, reverse, vite, sveltekit

I'm making a web application using Vite+SvelteKit. I know that SvelteKit is currently in a development state, but I wonder if this error could be fixed in anyway in my code.
Everything works just fine except this: I have a simple component, in which I import an array of objects which I iterate using each. I want to reverse the array before iteration, in order for the each construct to show the elements from the last one to the first one:

```
import { w, p } from '../../js/data.js'
let wRev = w.reverse()

{#each wRev as article, i}
  <article>
    {article.title} {article.author} {article.data}
  </article>
{/each}
```

The data.js array of objects is very simple:

```
let w = [{title: ..., author: ..., data: ...}, {...}]
```

Now SvelteKit doesn't render the reverse operation in time.
I'm using Vite, so I use automatic hot-reload (automatic page reload on save). The app is showing the array in the natural (not reversed) order. If I MANUALLY reload the page, it shows the reversed array.
With ctrl + s, browser shows:

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

Same browser tab, manual reload, it correctly shows:

- item 3
- item 2
- item 1

then, crtl+s after an edit somewhere in the code, then again item 1, item 2, item 3.

This issue only happens with this each rendering, other stuffs are rendered correctly in time.
I wonder if:

- SvelteKit isn't able to reverse the array in time for Vite/hot-reloading to show it. Actually, the array is composed by 20-30 objects, it's not that large
- I can apply some strategy in order to load chunks of the array and load the others by pressing the common "more" button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the imported data is mutated. So every time the code of the page is executed on hot-reload, the array is reversed. On initial load it will always be consistent but after that it will flip back and forth.

I would recommend *not* mutating the source data by creating a local copy first:

```js
let wRev = w.slice().reverse()
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, what do you mean with "mutated"? Is there some official documentation/explanation about this concept?

Comment: See e.g. the Wikipedia article on [immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This is a general programming concept. The `reverse` function modifies the object *in place*, i.e. causes a mutation; other methods like `filter` do not.